# 'Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I'm calling a procedure from entity framework and passing a `DateTime` parameter value like this:

```
("@dtAnsweredOn", SqlDbType.DateTime, objTestApplicationTaskProperty.AnsweredTime.Value )
```

> 'Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime'

`AnsweredTime` is a c# property which returns a datetime object

```
private Nullable<DateTime> dtAnsweredTime = null;

public Nullable<DateTime> AnsweredTime
{
    get { return dtAnsweredTime; }
    set { dtAnsweredTime = value; }
}
```

The parameter is defined in my procedure like `@dtAnsweredOn DATETIME`. what am I missing?

---

**EDIT :**

As others suggested, this is my sql code in procedure wherever `@dtAnsweredOn` has been used. FYI `dtCreatedOn` is also a datetime column.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Some_Proc]
(...
 @dtAnsweredOn datetime,
 ...
)
AS                                                    
BEGIN
 IF(Some_Condition)
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Some_Table (... dtCreatedOn...)
   VALUES (...@dtAnsweredOn...)
  END
 ELSE
  BEGIN
   UPDATE Some_Table SET Some_column = Some_value  
   WHERE dtCreatedOn = @dtAnsweredOn
  END
END
```

**

### UPDATE

**

With Profiler I can see the value passed to the procedure is considered as nvarchar in t-sql for some unknown reason `@dtAnsweredOn=N'25.01.2018 16:08:57'`

Comment: mentioned in the header: 'Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime'

Comment: Ahh so you did, even still

Comment: which value you pass?

Comment: objTestApplicationTaskProperty.AnsweredTime.Value ???

Comment: how about explicitly converting the value? `Convert.ToDateTime(objTestApplicationTaskProperty.AnsweredTime.Value)`

Comment: It's an SQL Server error message. We need to see the SQL code. @JohnWoo - what value do you think that [function call](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,6ece67905d76d903) is adding to the code?

Comment: Check data type of `@dtAnsweredOn` parameter in SQL, is it `nvarchar` instead of `datetime`? Or something else trying to insert `nvarchar` value to `datetime` column?

Comment: You could use the SQL Server Profiler to monitor what is passed over acutally. This happens mainly in connection with culture specific date formats, where e.g. `2017-01-02` can be the first of Feb and the second of Jan on another system. A date like `2017-01-13` works with 13th of Jan but breaks otherwise... Even worse are formats like `17/01/02`, which can be misinterpreted very easily. The worst are language specific formats such as `12 Dec 2017`

Comment: @Shnugo - at the moment, from the C# side, everything looks right. ADO.Net (ultimately) should be receiving a `DateTime` value and translating it into a SQL Server `datetime` value. *formats* shouldn't come into this since there aren't any *strings* involved here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, well, sure, but... Somewhere this error occurs - and it occurs within SQL Server. If there is something in between (e.g. a stored proc) which accepts the value as string, implicit conversions take place. Within one single system implicit conversions tend to work correctly if done bi-drectional. Might be, that *I'm calling a procedure* points to this. Might be, that this proc is defined with the date as a string. And I assume, that the value is converted and re-converted in two systems... But this is pure guessing...

Comment: If possible, try using profiler and check procedure call. Execute the same in sql server and troubleshoot.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever see the updated question. I have tried with different formats like 'dd/mm/yyy', 'dd.mm.yyyy' etc but no luck.

Comment: If those are the only uses within the stored procedure and all of the data types are correct then it's time to start looking for a bad trigger on `Some_Table`.

Comment: @izengod What do you mean by *"I have tried with different **formats**"*? Where? According to your post and comments, all the data (parameter, column) are dates and there are no strings involved, so what **format** are you talking about? Is there something that we don't see?

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried the formats in SSMS while passing the value in the proc.

Comment: Also can we see the other parameters of the SP. In case you have another string parameter and called the SP with wrong parameters (in the C# call site). Wait... Are you saying you can't call the SP even from SSMS?

Comment: In this code: "UPDATE Some_Table SET Some_column = Some_value  
   WHERE dtCreatedOn = @dtAnsweredOn" what is the type of dtCreatedOn?

Comment: @IvanStoev I double checked with that, there is no mismatch of params.

Comment: And what about dtCreatedOn, what is its data type?

Comment: @sepupic that's also datetime, i already mentioned in the post.

Comment: Why don't you use Profiler as was suggested above? Please update your question with the procedure call as you see it in Profiler

Comment: @sepupic please see the update with profiler.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: >>>is considered as nvarchar in t-sql for some unknown reason<<< It's not just "considered" as nvarchar, it's pure nvarchar. And this is not a server that transforms it, it's your code to pass a string instead of datetime

Comment: So you have 2 ways to fix this: 1. rewrite your c# code to make it pass date as a date 2. rewrite your sp changing its parameter type to nvarchar and then convert the value to datetime using appropriate style. N1 is better but I don't know c# so I cannot suggest you how to pass date as a date

Comment: @IvanStoev man, Idk what am I missing but it passes a datetime object clearly, no string is involved here.

Comment: Let start from the beginning. What is this `("@dtAnsweredOn", SqlDbType.DateTime, objTestApplicationTaskProperty.AnsweredTime.Value )`? I don't see a matching `SqlParameter` constructor. Or better show the whole EF call, e.g. `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(???)`